# Performance problems when accessing the nativeElement.offsetWidth or scrollWidth properties

Tags: angular

Suppose I have a css class to truncate text:

```css
.text-truncate {
  min-width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And I want to add a tooltip if it is truncated actually. For this purpose I created a directive:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[textTruncate]'
})
export class TextTruncateDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2
  ) {}

  @HostBinding('class')
  className = 'text-truncate';

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const text = this.el.nativeElement.textContent;
    if (text && this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth < this.el.nativeElement.scrollWidth) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'title', text);
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine only if I don't have a lot of elements where this directive is applied on.
If I have, for example, a table which has 10 columns and couple of hundreds of rows and I apply this directive to each cell, the fact I access `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth` properties of native element slows down my app hundred times. It works, but it's freaking slow.

If I replace this code:

```
if (text && this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth < this.el.nativeElement.scrollWidth) {
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'title', text);
}
```

for just `this.renderer.setAttribute(...)` without any conditions, it starts working pretty fast.
I just wondering what is the reason? and is there a way to optimize it somehow?

PS. I don't use a `table` actually, just a lot of `div`s. But I don't think it's matter.

Comment: What's your `@HostBinding` for?

Comment: @MathewBerg to apply css class obviously.

Comment: TIL! Didn't know you could do it like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that calling `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth` leads to reflow. See also [What forces layout/reflow](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a).

In your case you should try to minimize or replace these before mentioned calls.
A few resources which might be helpful in addition:

- [Avoid Large, Complex Layouts and Layout Thrashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing)
- [Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/browser-reflow)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar directive in AngularJS 1.8 and faced the same problem of reflow calculation on reading offsetWidth.

I mitigated the early reflow by deciding the title on "mouseenter" instead of precalculating it.